# Wireless keyboard hiccups and random repeats

Tags: windows, wireless-keyboard

I bought two wireless keyboards from different brands and they both seem to have an issues that some keys are randomly repeated (this happens from time to time), and on other occasions there is just a simple hiccup and the transmission doesn't work properly. This happens around once every 1-3min.

Any suggestions what could be the cause for this and how it can be debugged? One of the keyboards is from Logitech (K800), so it is a decent brand, and it's not bluetooth.

Comment: Make sure keyboard and transmitted are running the latest firmware version. AFAIR some months ago several serious vulnerabilities were found in the Logitech non-Bluetooth system allowing to e.g,. Inject key strokes.

Comment: the issue also occurs with non-logitech keyboard. It's more likley connected to windows itself